# How to solve the unable to find inherited method for function for signature "nls"?

Tags: r, nls, inherited

How to solve the unable to find inherited method for function for signature "nls"?

[When using the nls function this problem appears constantly. R is not able to summarize it in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m4EB.png)

I've been trying to fit my data points with the formula showed in nls, in order to then create a graph. Unfortunately I can't get my fitted data points because of this error.

I would be thankful for any kind of feedback on what the problem could be!

I've tried inserting my documents anew and repeating everything again.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add images of code / errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. I can't tell (as you use an image but do you have `Summary` e.g. an uppercase `S` instead of lowercase. Otherwise, I'd restart R and do not load any previous worksace and start again.

Comment: I can reproduce error if using (incorrectly) an uppercase `S` with `fm1DNase1 <- nls(density ~ SSlogis(log(conc), Asym, xmid, scal), subset(DNase, Run == 1)) ; Summary(fm1DNase1)` . Can you conffirm this is what has caused the errorplesse?